# ng-click not triggered while on the same DOM element as ng-show

Tags: angularjs

In this case:

`<div ng-show="isVisible" ng-click="do_something()">Test</div>`

when `isVisible` is set to `true` then `false`, the `ngClick` directive don't work.

I presume it has to do with some Angular DOM compilation and binding.

What is the best practice to make sure ngClick is binded?

Note: I am on Angular 1.1.5.

Comment: Can you provide a Fiddle please ?

Comment: You want to be able to click an invisible div or do you want to click it after it is set to visible again?

Comment: When it is set to visible again.